# Firefox won't recognize coding! returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

So my problem is Firefox doesn't recognize .innerText which is used to retrieve the current users name and added to the URL. This works in Safari, Chrome, and IE, but not Firefox. It returns "undefined"

```
function toggle_visibility( id ) { 

var url = 'http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=46780594e96e435ff18e44e48b7d880d&amp;ser‌ver=irc.Mibbit.Net&amp;channel=%23yourCh&nick=',
        username = document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].innerText;
    document.getElementById( 'chat' ).setAttribute( 'href', url + username );
```

So I found this solution for Firefox that needs to be added.

```
if(document.all){
     document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].innerText;
} 

else{
    document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0].textContent;
}
```

I need help using the .textContent to retrieve the username in Firefox and still use .innerText also. I'm hoping it's going in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check for `document.all` to use `innerText`.

Also, the official property is `textContent`. You should prioritise that when you check.

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0],
    text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

`text` will contain the text nodes joined for the element.

Comment: `var url = 'http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=46780594e96e435ff18e44e48b7d880d&amp;server=irc.Mibbit.Net&amp;channel=%23FLOWcypher&nick=',
    elem = document.getElementsByClassName( 'user-nickname' )[0],
    username =  elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
document.getElementById( 'chat' ).setAttribute( 'href', url + username );`